# What am I doing wrong? Waveform generator and Oscilloscope test

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscilloscope, waveform

In the circuit below, PS1 is a waveform generator. Originally, there will be the secondary of a current transformer. R36 is a MOV, D11 is a TVS diode and R29 a burden resistor. D12 sets the non inverting input of the opamp to Vcc/2. With the waveform generator I generate a sine wave 3V peak to peak, or 1.5V peak with no offset. When the input voltage is this high, x1 x2 (analog switch) close to reduce the opamp gain close to unity. But for now I'm not powering up the opamp, or the whole circuit. The issue is this: first I check with the oscilloscope the output waveform of the generator and it's OK. But when I connect the generator to the circuit and I measure it with the scope, then the signal disappears, i.e., it measures zero. Note I'm not energizing the circuit yet. My expectation is that when I connect the generator, I should see the same signal, but when I power up the circuit then the signal should swing around 1.65V.

What can cause this? What am I misunderstanding and doing wrongly?

[image]

Comment: Your signal generator ground is connected to AC power ground but your circuit assumes it is floating. You are probably shorting D12 and modifying the bias voltages.

Comment: Oscilloscopes are Earth grounded. If your device is also Earth grounded then you have a short circuit.

Comment: The weird thing is that I don't energize the opamp circuit. So there's something wrong with the passive components (?)

Comment: IC behavior is undefined and generally ill-behaved without power applied. I wouldn't concern myself with oddities seen when power is off. If one side of your generator is actually connected to earth ground you can address that with capacitive coupling. R29 of 33 ohms is a very stiff load, may be attenuating things.

Comment: @td127 I tried without R29. And the same happens even when I energize the circuit.

Comment: Can you confirm you see 1.65V at TP9?

Comment: Yes, there's 1.65V.

Comment: So what do you see at TP7 and TP8?

Comment: When I connect the generator, I don't see anything at TP7/TP8. The signal goes away.

Comment: So with the generator in place, do you still see 1.65V at TP9, or did the addition of the generator drop that node to zero?

Comment: I still see the 1.65V at TP9. But I don't see the AC signal coming from the generator anymore.

Comment: Well you shouldn't see AC at TP9, only the 1.65V. But you should see AC at TP7 (probably should re-install R29, but maybe a little bigger)

Comment: I don't see the AC at TP7. I thought I could see the signal even if I don't have R29 installed.

Comment: what DC level do you see at TP7 (should be 1.65V also)

Comment: As a sanity check, why not try attaching the bottom side of your function generator to the gnd net instead of the TP9 net. You should now definitely see AC on the other side, connected to TP7. You should also see AC at the opamp output. You might not see anything at TP8 if it is in fact connected directly to a low-impedance ADC input, but you should see something at the opamp output pin. And by the way, what is that opamp? It has a strange pinout.